# iOS Safari header disappears when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, safari, header, keyboard, sticky

I have a website that uses the iOS safari tag „black-translucent“ and a coloured header that is „sticky“ to the top (the unsafe area), so that the time and battery (text color is white) is visible when the user scrolls.

Now when the user enters a text into a field and the keyboard shows up, the sticky header moves up and the time and battery (which are still white) are on top of my white website background and thus not visible.

How can I keep my header sticky to the top unsafe area when the keyboard is visible?

[keyboard not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XojAt.jpg)

[Keyboard shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uyFY.jpg)

I searched stackoverflow and found out that there seems to be some buggieness around the iOS keyboard and the visible areas..

Maybe there’s a sort of hack?
Maybe scroll?

Answer (score -1):

`header position absolute` did it for me whenever an input is in focus and reverts to sticky when input is out of focus.
With a seperate `ontouchmove event listener` the text field is blurred and keyboard gets hidden.
It's a bit hacky but it works especially on devices with a notch.